# Error in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new at Python. Here is my code which scans number of test cases `tc` as input and then two integers `r` and `c` and calculating my result.

Question: How to remove the error?

```
#!bin/bash/python
tc=int(input());
while tc:
    r,c=raw_input().split()
    if r%2==0:
        r=r/2
    else:
        r=r/2+1
    print(r*c)
    tc=tc-1

4       //input tc
10 10   //input r=10 c=10
```

Error displayed at the screen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "spoj_solders.py", line 5, in <module>
  if r%2==0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is this string formatting?

Platform: Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `r,c=raw_input().split()` takes text from the user (`raw_input()`), returns it as a `str` type and splits that into two strings (separated by a space) and stores those in the variables `r` and `c`. So, `r` is a `str`, you can't say `if r%2==0:` without casting `r` to an `int` like this:

```
r,c=raw_input().split()
if int(r)%2==0:
    r=int(r)/2
else:
    r=int(r)/2+1
print(r*c)
tc=tc-1
```

Comment: I want the answer 50 for r=10 & c=10 ,but is giving 1010101010,tc=4

Answer (score 2):

The result of the `split()` call is a list of strings, therefore the `r` and `c` variables are also strings.

So, when it comes to using the `%` operator on `r` Python is performaning string formatting and not the modulus operation you expect.

You need to cast `r` into a variable of the correct type first (using `float(r)` for example).

Comment: You should use `math.fmod()` if you are using a float. If the input is cast to an int instead of a float, using `r % 2` is fine. You could always check whether the user has entered a decimal point to determine which method to use.

Comment: @jozzas: Try `int("1e-5")` sometime.

Comment: @John if you expect users will provide input in scientific notation, your program should account for that too :)